# Writing to InfluxDB fails due to timestamp problem

Tags: influxdb

I want to write a data point to my influxdb via bash shell but the timestamp seems to cause problems.

```
root@server:UP [~]# curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=tbr' --data-binary 'codenarc maxPriority2Violations=917 maxPriority3Violations=3336 1593122400000000000'
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: application/json
Request-Id: 03666c3f-b7b5-11ea-8659-02420a0a1b02
X-Influxdb-Build: OSS
X-Influxdb-Error: unable to parse 'codenarc maxPriority2Violations=917 maxPriority3Violations=3336 1593122400000000000': bad timestamp
X-Influxdb-Version: 1.7.10
X-Request-Id: 03666c3f-b7b5-11ea-8659-02420a0a1b02
Date: Fri, 26 Jun 2020 13:57:46 GMT
Content-Length: 129

{"error":"unable to parse 'codenarc maxPriority2Violations=917 maxPriority3Violations=3336 1593122400000000000': bad timestamp"}
```

This is how I created the timestamp in the first place

```
def date = LocalDateTime.of(2020, Month.JUNE, 26, 0, 0, 0)    
def ms = date.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli()
TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(ms, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

So the timestamp is supposed to be in ns and I ensured that. Why is influxdb giving me that error message? What's wrong with that timestamp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a timestamp issue. You have missed comma between the data that you are passing. Kindly comma separate all of them except the timestamp field. Modified your curl request, try now.

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=tbr' --data-binary 'codenarc, maxPriority2Violations=917, maxPriority3Violations=3336 1593122400000000000'
```

One more example:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server02,region=us-west value=0.55 1422568543702900257'
```

Comment: Well, I missed the comma on purpose as I don't want to write any tags but only fields with this request. This comment here (https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/3600#issuecomment-129227958) suggested to spare the comma.
If I follow your suggestion, I write a tag to the DB which is not what I want here. Sorry, should have mentioned this.

Comment: A workaround is to add a dummy tag which can be ignored: `curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=tbr' --data-binary 'codenarc,ignore=1,maxPriority2Violations="916" maxPriority3Violations="3338" 1593122400000000000'`